# What are the rules for Russian ordinal indicators?

Tags: числительные

I believe Russian uses ordinal indicators (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... 100th) like this:

```
1-й
2-й
3-й
4-й
5-й
10-е
```

What are the rules for assigning the suffix?

Comment: There's no general rule. You can find each ordinal number in every dictionary.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! I have hard time figuring out your exact question. It looks like your examples are inconsistent: *10-е* is plural, the rest are singular masculine. Could you please clarify what exactly are you asking about? How do Russian ordinals decline? Thanks!

Comment: your assumption is wrong,  -й stands for masculine, while -e for neuter, so it can be, for instance, десятое or десятый.

Comment: In fact for all of the ordinals there will be the same suffix: -й for masculine, -я for feminine, and -е both for neuter and plural.

Comment: To choose the correct suffix, you need to know the grammatical gender of the noun that follows the numeral which you can look up in a dictionary. Then use -й for masculine, -я for feminine, -е for neuter or plural. Exception: -и for plural noun and number 3: 3-и сутки.

Comment: "Сутки" is a plural-only noun, similar to scissors, trousers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the numbered object, especially on grammatical gender and number of this, - like in the inflectional language. By the fact, ordinal numbers are adjectives. So, see the rules for adjective's endings and declinations.

[https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/первый](https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9)

[https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/второй](https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9)

[https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/третий](https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-es/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Somebody consider that one last letter is enough ( https://clck.ru/QsBDS ),
but , really, you can find often the two letters. : >
1-ый 2-ой 3-ий 4-ый 5-ый 6-ой 7-ой 8-ой 9-ый 10-ый
It's for the masculine gender.
The feminine gender are 1-ая,  and others the same.
The neuter gender are 1-ое , etc. .

The last digit in a number only is taken into account.
About adj. - Compare "краснЫЙ", f.e.

P.S.
Your "1-й" - it's masculine gender.
"10-е" - it's neuter gender ( 10-ое neuter gender, if it is singular object, or "десят-ые", 10-ые any gender, if it's a plural something; also one reason for two letters ).

P.P.S. https://youtu.be/r9KlGJ-R5RM :)

Comment: There are also case forms, like _в 5-м пункте 77-го параграфа_. A good article: https://ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/all/o-naraschenii-okonchaniy-chislitelnyh/

Comment: 1-ый is considered non-standard. Editors will have you skip the vowel of the ending, or the first vowel if there are two.

Comment: Nikolay Ershov. or 10-е.  Something becomes incomprehensible (see above) if the object isn't described elsewhere.  I don't see the point of it.

Comment: Пилум, not only _-ый_, but also _-ое_ is considered nonstandard, the rule is that there can be either 1 or 2 letters after a numeral, and 2 letters are allowed _only_ if it is a consonant + a vowel letter, two vowel letters in a row are not allowed. Have a look at what gramota.ru says about it: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99

Comment: Yellow Sky, you can read about this on link above too, but it's no matter. I don't consider this to be incorrect and illiterate just uniquely "because" someone there decided something in the "grammar academy", this alone is not a sufficient reason.